# Applescript command to move files in current folder with *.extension to the folder with Name inside this folder

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript

I'm newbie in Scripting. Can you please help with this:

I need to move files with *.extension in current (selected) folder to the folder with Name inside this current (selected) folder.

for example: Move all .zip files in Folder 1, to the folder ZIP inside Folder 1. But I need to use it as a service (something like: select Folder 1, control+click "Move all zip to ZIP")

Thanks guys!

Comment: Man I'm totally 0 at scripting (I'm a graphic designer), so I tried this (I tried to find some information in Google)

Comment: tell application "Finder" to set theSel to selection

tell application "Terminal"
 set theFol to POSIX path of ((item 1 of theSel) as text)
 if (count of windows) is not 0 then
  do script "mv " & quoted form of theFol & "/*.zip ~/ZIP" & quoted form of theFol & ";clear" in window 1
 else
  do script "mv *.zip ~/ZIP" & quoted form of theFol & ";clear"
 end if
 activate
 
end tell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer - More automated and with a context menu/item**
You can add a context item to Finder's menu (`Finder > Services`), which will only appear when you have a folder selected (the one you want to move the files from.)
*This is what you'll see when you have a folder selected:*
[image: Preview of Finder's context menu when folder selected after doing this]

**Follow these steps**
1. Open the "Automator" application. (command + spacebar & type ""Automator" to find)
2. Press "New Document" (bottom left corner), if this doesn't show just do command + n
3. Select "Service" (One with the gear icon) and press enter.
4. Select these options in the top bar, so it looks like this:
[image]

5. In the search field, type in "Run AppleScript"
6. Drag it into the blank space on the right:
   [image]

7. Delete all the script in there and paste in my script instead:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set fromFolder to item 1 of input
    -- Choose the file extension to be moved
    set fileExtension to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter the file extension you want to move." default answer "zip")
    -- This will put the files in a folder inside your selected folder with the name of the file extension
    -- e.g. move txt files in Kamil:Desktop:TextStuff will move it into Kamil:Desktop:TextStuff:txt
    -- Change it to what suits your needs
    set toFolder to fromFolder & fileExtension as string

    -- Finder will handle the moving of files
    tell application "Finder"

        set filesMoved to (every file of folder fromFolder whose name ends with fileExtension)
        move filesMoved to folder toFolder

        display notification "Into \"" & toFolder & "\"" with title "Moved " & (count of filesMoved) & " " & fileExtension & " files"

    end tell

end run
```

7. Press command + s and give it the name you want and press save.
8. Now quit Automator

---

Now open a Finder window and select a folder with a folder created inside it named the file extension you will be sorting; go to `Finder > Services > [What you named it]`,
type in the file extension and press enter.
You should see a notification when it's done moving the files, which tells you how many were moved and to which folder.
I hope this better answers your request, and if does, don't forget to mark it as the answer, otherwise, comment on it and l'll see what I can do.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! It's interesting decision, but it's takes too much time (I mean I can select all zip's by sorting by Kind in Finder and drag it to the destination folder) I need it more automatic. Anyway thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Okay. I re-read your question, and I want to clarify, do you want your folder paths to be hardcoded (meaning they won't change, they'll always be in the same spot)? If so, I can change my script and you wouldn't need to select the folder(s).

Comment: Actually, I think I know a method that could better automate this task. In an hour or so when I'm not busy, l'll update my answer.

Comment: @ArtemDemidenko I've updated my answer, I hope it answers your request.

Comment: OMG Thank you very much! It's really works for me now. Thank you for your answer You are the king of scripting! :)

Comment: No problem. If you're happy with my answer, don't forget to mark it as the answer.